# Как на Windows NTFS сделать права доступа для "Сертификата организации", так с целью только на 2-х ПК был доступ?

Tags: windows, администрирование, права, ntfs

1. Например где генерировать и устанавливать сертификат который использовался как "Сертификат организации"
2. "Сертификат организации" - субъект прав доступа, подобно "система", "администраторы"

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем суть вопроса.

Comment: как в своё время говорил мне зав. кафедры - Павел тебе надо учится говорить

Comment: 2) "Сертификат организации" - субъект прав доступа, подобно "система", "администраторы"